# IGBT modelling from datasheet

Tags: power, power-electronics, semiconductors, modeling, igbt

how to model igbt from the APT150GN120J datasheet.

```
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 160 64 160 -32
WIRE 112 144 48 144
WIRE 336 160 160 160
FLAG 48 224 0
FLAG 160 -112 0
FLAG 336 240 0
SYMBOL Misc\\NIGBT 112 64 R0
SYMATTR InstName Z1
SYMBOL voltage 48 128 R0
WINDOW 3 -104 149 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 1 0 0 0 12.5e-3 25e-3)
SYMBOL voltage 160 -16 R180
WINDOW 0 24 96 Left 2
WINDOW 3 24 16 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 25
SYMBOL res 320 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 10
TEXT 256 64 Left 2 !Z1 C G E M1 [1e-4] [off] [temp=25]
TEXT 256 88 Left 2 !.model M1 NIGBT
TEXT -58 298 Left 2 !.tran 20m
```

using this coomands

Zxxx C G E MNAME [area] [m=] [off] [temp=]

.model MNAME NIGBT

how to obtain this values from above datasheet to model the igbt
[image]

Comment: 1) What you call "datasheet" is not a datasheet. I don't know what it is supposed to be. A proper datasheet for an IGBT looks like this: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-FS650R08A4P2-DataSheet-v03_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46272e49d2a017351f435eb5977  2) the **model** of a device is based on the actual construction of the transistor, like thickness of gate oxide, doping levels, geometry (length and width). This information is only available to the **manufacturer**.

Comment: 3) the normal way how transistor models are made is that the transistor is measured on specialist equipment (like a semiconductor parameter analyzer) under various conditions and that the resulting measured data is used (using specialist software) to create the model parameters. This is **work for specialists**. TLDR: you simply cannot make a model from a "datasheet". I suggest that you ask the manufacturer for a model.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie is it possible derive the value of Ron, Roff, Vth, Vhs, Ls, Rs values of IGBT using that datasheet so i can use those values for designing VCSW?